# Trying to Convert a Text file into data structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have like this text data as following contents. What am i trying is to convert this text into data structure(`Lists of dictionaries` or `list of lists`) to be able to handle with.

> test.txt

```
0           1           1
3,1         3,1         3,1
5,0         5,1         5,0
6,1         6,0         6,0
```

Output formate like this:

```
   0     1      1
   ---------------
3| 1    1       1
5| 0    1      0
6| 1    0       0
```

I tried lot of things but unfortunately it did not succeeded.

Comment: What structure do you want? List of lists? Lists of dictionaries? Dictionaries of lists? Dictionaries of dictionaries?

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far? What's the issue with your current code?

Comment: I am beginner so i spent a lot of time with trying to understand how to do it, but nothing succeeded

Comment: Could you publish your code and (if present) error messages? Also, what do you want to do about the fact that you have two columns called `1`?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: Where is the [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is exactly the structure you want, but try this:

```
import collections

txt = """0           1           1
3,1         3,1         3,1
5,0         5,1         5,0
6,1         6,0         6,0"""

header = list(map(int,txt.splitlines()[0].split()))

output = collections.OrderedDict()
for line in txt.splitlines()[1:]:
    cols = line.split()
    row_num = int(cols[0].split(",")[0])

    vals = [(header[i],int(c.split(",")[1])) for i, c in enumerate(cols)]
    output[row_num] = vals

print(output)
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('3', [(0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1)]), ('5', [(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0)]), ('6', [(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 0)])])
```

---

To load a file:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    txt = f.read()
```

Comment: thanks but in my case its about a txt file and not a txt `String`

Comment: And yes its exactly what i need

Comment: Could you please update your answer so that its suitable with `file.txt`?

Comment: `with open('result.info') as infile:
    header = list(map(int,infile.read().splitlines()[0].split()))
    output = collections.OrderedDict()
    for line in infile.read().splitlines()[1:]:
        print(line)
        cols = line.split()
        row_num = cols[0][0]
        vals = [(header[i],int(c.split(",")[1])) for i, c in enumerate(cols)]
        output[row_num] = vals
    print(output)`

Comment: where am i doing error? i am getting empty OrderedDict

Comment: The issue there is that `infile.read()` only works once... I'll edit :)

Comment: One last issue, what if i have a integer number like `10` or `12` in the `file.txt`? it takes always the first index of it and prints `1`

Comment: I have a question please . how can i access the elements of `OrderedDict `? for example i want to get the sum of  `1`of all columns ? in this case `1` occurs twice and `0` just ons  this will be the last question :)

Comment: @Alex You should be able to treat OrderedDict like any other dict, read the docs.